# Need some help finding bug in Parse CloudCode function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, save, promise, backend

I wrote this function to work on parse's CloudCode, it supposed to do the following

1. Query for artist that need to be update - works fine
2. For each artist make a Parse.Cloud.httpRequest to retrieve  JSON of upcoming gigs - works fine
3. Parse and save each JSON object - Seems to be parsing fine - but its not saving anything to the backend even tho it is returning successful

**The Problem**
- the function returns successful when I run it on could code but none of the objects or classes get saved to the backend

**Global's and main function**

```js
var Venue = Parse.Object.extend("Venue");
var Event = Parse.Object.extend("Event");
var ArtistObject = Parse.Object.extend("Artist");
var _ = require('underscore');


Parse.Cloud.job("updateUpcomingGigs", function(response)  {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    
    getArtistThatNeedToBeUpdated().then(function(results){
        var firstprommises = [];
           
        _.each(results,function(artist) {
            
          firstprommises.push(
                  
                    getJSONForArtist(artist).then(function(JSON){
                      return parseAndSaveUpcomingEventsAndVenues(JSON,artist); 
                    })
                   );
            
          });//end of loop for each artist 
        
        return Parse.Promise.when(firstprommises);
    
    }).then(function(){
        console.log('finished');
      response.success('Artist and venues Updated');
   }),function(error) {
        response.error(error);
  };//error promise 

 });
```

**GetArtistThatNeedToBeUpdated**

```js
function getArtistThatNeedToBeUpdated() {
    var d = new Date();
    //var lastWeeksDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() - 7);
    var lastWeeksDate = new Date(d.getTime());
    //var ArtistObject = Parse.Object.extend("Artist");
    //var artistObject = new ArtistObject;
    var query = new Parse.Query(ArtistObject);
    query.lessThan( "updatedAt", lastWeeksDate );
    console.log('get artist');
    return query.find();
}
```

**getJSONForArtist**

```js
function getJSONForArtist(artist){
    
   var encodedArtistName =  escape(artist.get("artistName")); 
   return  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ 
             url: "http://url goes here" 
            }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                //var JSON = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
                var JSON = httpResponse.data;
                //var resultes = JSON;
                return JSON;
            });
}
```

**parseAndSaveUpcomingEventsAndVenues - I think the problem lies in here somewhere**

```js
function parseAndSaveUpcomingEventsAndVenues(JSONObj,artist){
    
    var prommises = [];
    _.each(JSONObj,function(obj){
     

    if (obj){
    prommises.push(function(){ 
        
                   var event = new Event();
                   var currentVenue = new Venue();
                   var venue = obj.venue;//simple object
                   var artistArray = obj.artists[0];//digging down to top artist 
                    
                    var d = new Date(obj.datetime);
                    var monthIndex = d.getMonth();

                    return event.saveAsync(null,{
                       "artistName":artistArray.name,
                       "title":obj.title,
                       "formatted_datetime":obj.formatted_datetime,
                       "formatted_location":obj.formatted_location,
                       "monthIndex":monthIndex      
                       
                        }).then(function(){
                             var upcomingGigsRelation = artist.relation("upcomingGigsRelation");
                             upcomingGigsRelation.add(event);
                             return artist.saveAsync()
                            .then(function(){
                            return currentVenue.saveAsync(null,{
                                "venue": venue.name,
                                "city": venue.city,
                                "country":venue.county,
                                "region": venue.region,
                                "latitude": venue.latitude,
                                "longitude":venue.longitude       
                            }).then(function(){
                             var upcomingGigsRelation = currentVenue.relation("upcomingGigsRelation");
                             upcomingGigsRelation.add(event);
                            return currentVenue.saveAsync();
                             }); 
                           });
                         });
                       });//end of promise function
                     }else{
                        console.log('No JSON found');
                            return;
                     }
                  });//end of loop             
    return Parse.Promise.when(prommises).then(function(){
        console.log('done parsing object');
     }),function(error) {
        response.error(error);
  };                 
};
```

Would really appreciate any help, I logged out the information in the parse and save function and all the objects seem to be coming through just fine, I know at the moment there is a lack of defensive code in here but I really don think thats the issue.

Thanks - James

Comment: In `parseAndSaveUpcomingEventsAndVenues()` you push functions into an array named `promises`.

Comment: why are you using saveAsync? does it work on save?